# Setting background of imageView in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am setting a background of an imageView of a relative layout using Helper.sync_settting_2(img_sync, context).

```
 try {
            final RelativeLayout layout_img_sync = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_lay_6);
            final ImageView img_sync = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_sync);
            layout_img_sync.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Helper.sync_settting_2(img_sync, context);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
    };
```

Here is the function Helper.sync_settting_2(ImageView sync, Context ct).

```
 public static void sync_settting_2(ImageView sync, Context ct) {
    Toast.makeText(ct, "Sync Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getJobData getJobs = new getJobData(null);
    sync.setBackground(ct.getResources().getDrawable(
            com.org.courier.R.drawable.sync_image_orange));
    getJobs.setOnApiLIstner(new onApiCompleted() {
        @Override
        public void onApiResults(ArrayList<job_entity> events_list) {
            getMessageData getMessage = new getMessageData(null);
            getMessage.setOnApiLIstner(new getMessageData.onApiCompleted() {

                @Override
                public void onApiResults(
                        ArrayList<message_entity> events_list) {
                    getContactData getContact = new getContactData(null);
                    getContact
                            .setOnApiLIstner(new getContactData.onApiCompleted() {

                                @Override
                                public void onApiResults(
                                        ArrayList<contact_entity> events_list) {
                                }
                            });
                    getContact.execute();
                }
            });
            getMessage.execute();
        }
    });
    getJobs.execute();
    sync.setBackground(ct.getResources().getDrawable(
            com.org.courier.R.drawable.sync_image_03));
    Toast.makeText(ct, "Sync Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();
}
```

It showing an error

> "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget,ImageView.setBackground"

Comment: You should take your imageView in a relative layout and set the background to the layout. The error says that ImageView doesn't have a method SetBackground

Comment: Its in the relative layout.

Comment: Ok but do you set the background image to the layout or the imageview ? Because this error explicitly means that you are trying to do setBackground() to an ImageView ;) which doen't works

Comment: I am setting background image to the imageview. See function sync_setting_2(ImageView, context).

Comment: hahaha so what should i do now :/?

Comment: Yes this is what's caussing the error, you should set the background image another way. When you say "background image" you mean that you have an imageview with an image and you want an image behind ? or the imageview  IS the background ?

Comment: @Yume117 why can't you set the background of an `ImageView`? It inherents from `View`, right? Where is this documented?

Comment: Actually in simple words I want to replace the current image with the image present in drawable.

Comment: sync here is the imageView.

sync.setBackground(ct.getResources().getDrawable(
            com.org.courier.R.drawable.sync_image_orange));

Answer (score 12, accepted):

View.setBackground wasn't added until API 16. I ran into this issue myself, and couldn't figure out for the life of me why it was happening, since I didn't get any newAPI warnings.

If you want it to be compatible with all versions of Android, you should use:

[setBackgroundResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)
or
[setBackgroundDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

However, for an ImageView, you should instead be setting the SRC, not the Background:

setImageResource() or setImageDrawable()

Comment: Its not showing the error and also its not changing the imageBackground :/.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to be changing the background and not the src? You should be using: setImageResource() or setImageDrawable() instead of changing the background.

Comment: No problem, I'm adding that to the solution as well!